# Two DIV's with auto-width

Tags: html, css

In my layout in the main part of site I need two flexible columns. The height is known and always the same. But the width should be auto-increases with the width of the browser.

[image]

I need this because in div#1 should be different content (float right I supposed) and background than in div#2 (float left I supposed). Whole layout is increasing their width with browser (width 100%).

It would be easy to make if the background of div 1 and 2 is the same (wrapper + background set on parent) but in this example backgrounds are different. I do not know how to auto-increase the width of these two divs.

Comment: That would be my first advice as well, just give each of them a width in percent so they sum up at 100%.

Comment: I did this morning and it worked for me `50%`

Answer (score 4):

adjust the width parameter of `div#1` and `div#2`

```
    div #header {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    div #div1 {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        width: 50%;
        left: 0px;
    }

    div #div2 {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        width: 50%;
        right: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            This is header
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="div1">
            This is left div
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            This is right div
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer">
            This is footer
        </div>
    </div>

.container{
    max-width:960px;
    padding:0 15px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}

.header{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.div1{
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    background-color:pink;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.div2{
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    background-color:green;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

.footer{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    background-color:cyan;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

I've created a [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/64yo50wv/)

Answer (score 0):

What about a good, simple, semantic layout? The below uses positioning to maintain a fixed footer, here is an [example without](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/d54Le1Lg/1/)

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/d54Le1Lg/)

HTML

```
<header></header>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
header, footer, section {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
header, footer {
    background:green;
    height:50px;
}
footer {
    bottom:0;
}
section {
    top:50px;
    bottom:50px;
    width:50%;
    background:yellow;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
section:last-of-type {
    background:blue;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
}
#div1{
    height:400px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#div2{
    height:400px;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
#footer{
    width:100%;
}
```